Collisions in Raylib C++
Im making this simple platform game on Raylib C++, and I can't nail down the collisions. I have tried to implement my own collisions:
#include "raylib.h"
#include <stdio.h>

struct square
{
    // Variables 
    float x, y;
    float w, h;
   float gravity;
    float velocity;

    Rectangle GetRectangle() { //            x   w   h
        return Rectangle{ x - w / 2, y - h / x, 80, 80 };
    }
    int drawsquare() {
        DrawRectangleRec(GetRectangle(), RED);
        return 0;
    }
};
struct obby
{
    // Variables 
    float x, y;
    float w, h;

    Rectangle GetRectangle() {
        return Rectangle{ x, y, w, h };
    }
    int drawobby() {
        DrawRectangleRec(GetRectangle(), BROWN);
        return 0;
    }
};

int currentLevel = 1;

int main(void) 
{
    InitWindow(1100, 700, "Basic Platformer");

    SetWindowState(FLAG_VSYNC_HINT);

    // Player Attributes
    square player;
    player.x = 100;
    player.y = 400;
    player.w = 80;
    player.h = 80;
    player.gravity = 0.0f;
    player.velocity = 0.15f;

    // Floor Attributes
    obby floor1;
    floor1.x = 50;
    floor1.y = 575;
    floor1.w = 160;
    floor1.h = 30;

    // DeltaTime
    float deltaTime = GetFrameTime();

    // Sets the FPS
    SetTargetFPS(60);

    // While Window is Open
    while (!WindowShouldClose()) 
    {
        // Player Gravity / Physics
        player.gravity += player.velocity;
        player.y += player.gravity;

        // Collisions
        if (CheckCollisionRecs(player.GetRectangle(), floor1.GetRectangle())) {
            player.y = floor1.y - 80;
            player.gravity = 0;
        }

        // Input
        if (IsKeyPressed(KEY_W)) {
            player.gravity = -5;
        }
        else if (IsKeyDown(KEY_A)) {
            player.x -= 4;
        }
        else if (IsKeyDown(KEY_D)) {
            player.x += 4;
            currentLevel = 2;
        }

        BeginDrawing();

        // Level 1
        if (currentLevel == 1) {
            void Level1(void);
            {
                floor1.drawobby();
            }
        }

        // Level 2
        if (currentLevel == 2) {
            void Level1(void);
            {

           }
        }

        // Level 3
        if (currentLevel == 3) {
            void Level1(void);
            {

            }
        }

        ClearBackground(GRAY);
        player.drawsquare();

        EndDrawing();

        // DeltaTime
        deltaTime = GetFrameTime();
    }


    CloseWindow();

    return 0;
}

...but it only works for the top of the floor object my player is trying to stand on.
Also, don't worry about the  Level voids those are just there for the future.

Usage note: When the formatting of the code example looks that ed up, you owe it to yourself to read some of the documentation on how to format it correctly. Stack Overflow outright sucks at getting that sort oof information in your face, but there are links scattered around the Ask a Question page, the More link at the top of the text box beside the formatting buttons, is particularly useful.

Side note: We do need to talk a bit about the level voids. You cannot embed a function inside a function (but take a quick look at lambda expressions), so if those are place-holders for stuff to come later, those place holders need to be elsewhere in the code. Further, the example code in a question should be a [mre] or as close to it as possible. That means you want code that is the bug, the whole bug, and nothing but the bug. Placeholders for future stuff just add noise, and noise is detrimental to a question.

Usage note: I've searched many tutorials for collisions but I haven't found one that fits my situation. adds nothing to the question unless you define your situation. If we don't know what the situation is, we can't make any non-general suggestions and presumably the tutorials will have already covered most or all of these general suggestions.
